# WCF Service testing with connections external to localhost

Tags: wcf

I'm developing a WCF webservice, but when it loads via visual studio in the built in server (Cassini) I cannot access it anyway except via localhost on that machine.  I would like to try it with connections from other machines as well though... what's the best way to do this without installing IIS on my box (I can't...stupid system corporate policies prevent it).

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use / install IIS Express ([see this link](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1003/running-iis-express-without-administrative-privileges/)) without administrative privileges. However sadly Cassini does not allow remote connections.

Comment: well that settles it... this was driving me crazy!

Comment: I worked somewhere that had a stupid policy like the one which you are constrained by, you have my sympathy

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you should install IIS.  Cassini does not support remote connections.